# Create single row for each entry in df rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I read in an excel file as a DataFrame whose rows contains multiple values. The shape of the df is like:

```
                                             Welding
0  65051020                                      ...
1  66053510                          66053550    ...
2  66553540                66553560              ...
3  67053540                  67053505            ...
```

now I want to split each row and write each entry into an own row like

```
    Welding
0   65051020
1   66053510
2   66053550
....
n   67053505
```

I tried have tried:

```
[new.append(df.loc[i,"Welding"].split()) for i in range(len(df))]

df2=pd.DataFrame({"Welding":new})

print(df2)

                                             Welding
0                                            66053510
1                                            66053550
2                                            66053540
3                                            66053505
4                                            66053551
5   [65051020, 65051010, 65051030, 65051035, 65051...
6   [66053510, 66053550, 66053540, 66053505, 66053...
7   [66553540, 66553560, 66553505, 66553520, 66553...
8                      [67053540, 67053505, 67057505]
9   [65051020, 65051010, 65051030, 65051035, 65051...
10  [66053510, 66053550, 66053540, 66053505, 66053...
11  [66553540, 66553560, 66553505, 66553520, 66553...
12                     [67053540, 67053505, 67057505]
13  [65051020, 65051010, 65051030, 65051035, 65051...
14  [66053510, 66053550, 66053540, 66053505, 66053...
15  [66553540, 66553560, 66553505, 66553520, 66553...
16                     [67053540, 67053505, 67057505]
```

But this did not return the expected results.

Appreciate each help!

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Welding' : df.stack().values})` That's it.

Comment: If that's not what you're looking for, I recommend doing this: `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` so we know how to reconstruct your input properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df['Welding'].str.split(expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('Welding')
print (df)
    Welding
0  65051020
1  66053510
2  66053550
3  66553540
4  66553560
5  67053540
6  67053505
```